# Adding Number of Views to Web Page from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pageviews

I'm using Google Analytics on my blog. I want to display the number of page views for each post using the data captured by Google Analytics: e.g., "This post has been viewed **100** times", etc.

I haven't found any demo showing how to get that data from GA. Are there any suggestions for doing that? Ideally in JavaScript but I can work with other languages, too.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

Answer (score 0):

Using the reporting API might not be a good option. The free version of GA could take up anywhere from 24-48 hours at most to update the data. So your pageview counters won't always be the most up to date value OR realtime. Plus, once you go over certain date range then you'll have issues with sampling of that metric.

You might be better off just showing a free web hit counter.